# PassportJS: Is it possible to not serialize a user when connecting an account?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, serialization, passport.js

My app lets a user set up multiple oAuth connections to his account via PassportJS.

Whenever I connect another app (using the Mailchimp strategy and the Salesforce strategy), Passport logs me out (ends my `express-session`). It seems like Passport is trying to log in with a new session for every strategy I connect, which is not what I want at all.

I think the secret lies in the strategy callback I'm using, namely with the `done()` function returned:

```
passport.use(new MailChimpStrategy({
    clientID: auth.mailchimpAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: auth.mailchimpAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: auth.mailchimpAuth.callback
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        Chimp.findOne({'login_name': profile._json.login.login_name},               
        function(err, chimp) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!chimp) {
                var newChimp = new Chimp();
                newChimp.login_name = profile._json.login.login_name;
                newChimp.profile = profile;
                newChimp.authUsers = [];
                newChimp.domain = '';
                newChimp.accessToken = accessToken;
                newChimp.lists = {};
                newChimp.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return done(err);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, newChimp);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                var newChimp = chimp;
                return done(null, newChimp);
            }
        });
    });
}));
```

Presumably, this is because Passport things my user is changing when I authenticate with a new API. I can see this by inspecting `user.id` object being passed to `passport.serializeuser()` and `passport.deserializeuser()`. But I'm not making a new user here - I'm just adding the profile returned by each API to my original user account.

**How can I prevent this from happening and keep my original session active?**

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution to this (for whoever upvoted this question):

I was correct in thinking it has something to do with the `done()` being returned; what happens is that `done()` returns an object to `serializeUser()`, which then passes it to `deserializeUser()`.

So in my `mailChimpStrategy` function, I add `passReqToCallback: true`, then access the logged-in user from the callback function:

```
passport.use(new MailChimpStrategy({
    clientID: auth.mailchimpAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: auth.mailchimpAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: auth.mailchimpAuth.callback,
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    var tempUser = {id: req.session.passport.user}
    User.findById(tempUser.id, function(err, usr){
      var newChimp = new Chimp(); // Make new Mongoose Chimp object
          // Do Chimp profile setting here
          // Then, when done, instead of passing the Chimp profile object, I pass the user ID.
      return done(null, tempUser);
    })
});
```

Done and done.